# Keras loaded model dont have same accuracy

Tags: python, keras, save, load

I save my model with checkpoint,

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("Models/FVA_MEL.h5", monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max', period=1)
```

I load my model with load_model with

`from keras.models import load_model,save_model
modell = load_model("Models/FVA_MEL.h5")`

But loaded model doesn't have same accuracy with same test data i tried saving as .tf but it didn't work. Please help me

Comment: Did you test on the same images ? In which format do you insert the images into the CNN (uint8 (0-255) or float32 (0-1)) ? Do you have model-augmentation like Gaussian-Noise layers ?

Comment: how's the difference? How you're testing? Are you checking against val_accuracy?

Comment: I am checking val_accuracy, test images after loading model are same images as when i test during training

Answer (score 0):

Check Keras documentation first: https://keras.io/callbacks/

It might be discrepancy between "save_best_only=True" and weights for last epoch.
You should use weights for last epoch instead the best one.

Skeleton (see below section by section):

```
#{model}
{model = Sequential()}
{Your model}

#{model.comply}
#{model.compile()}
#{model.fit()}
#{model.save('your_name.h5')}
```

My example below:

```
# model
input_shape=(100,50,layers)
model = Sequential()
activation = 'relu'
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3),data_format='channels_last', input_shape=input_shape, padding='same', activation=activation))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation=activation))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(n_levels, activation='softmax'))
# model.save() # if you want to save model structure only (no weights)

# or (if you have saved model in JSON)
#with open(os.path.join(models_wd,model_name), 'r') as model_file:
#    model = model_from_json(model_file.read())
#    model_file.close()

#{model.compile}
adam = optimizers.Adam()
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.001, patience=12, verbose=1, mode='auto', baseline=None, restore_best_weights=False)
learning_rate_reduction = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='auto', cooldown=0, min_lr=0.00001)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=adam)
#{model.summary}
model.summary()
#{model.fit}
history = model.fit(xtr, ytr, batch_size=8, epochs=n_epochs, verbose=2, validation_data=(xest,yest), callbacks=[learning_rate_reduction, early_stopping])

#{model.save('your_name.h5')}               
model.save('your_name.h5')
```

Then in your_name.h5 file you will get same weights as last epoch, which give you same result after load model.